# Way to encapsulate functional tests in codeception

Tags: php, functional-testing

Codeception provides unit, **functional** and acceptance tests. It is built on top of phpunit. Phpunit allows you to run multiple tests within the same .php test file by making them functions of the test class:

```
<?php
class someTest {

   public function sample1Test() {
      //Test body
   }

  public function sample2Test() {
    //Test body
  }

  //etc
}
```

This allows you to have multiple tests per .php file, as the tests are all functions in a class. You can have multiple tests with multiple assertions.

However, all the functional tests in the **codeception** documentation seem to be limited to one test. You can have multiple assertions, but only one test per file this way.

I've searched through everything I can find, but can see no way to have multiple tests run out of the same .php test file when doing functional tests in codeception. *Does anyone know if it is possible to encapsulate different tests in the same file like you can with the others?*

Comment: That should work. It's similar to my functional tests which have multiple test methods per class. The big difference is that your methods don't have a parameter which they really should.